# BigQuery SELECT gives "There is no data to display" but preview shows data I just added

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I preview a table in BigQuery, I can see some test data I've just inserted via the .NET SDK.

But when I run the following SQL I get nothing.

```sql
SELECT workplaceKey FROM `acme-capricorn-sigma.abc_us_east1.SomeTable` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2023-02-20" LIMIT 1000
```

The SQL is the "suggested" template SQL in the GCP web console, I've just added a single column name.

I've configured partitioning by MONTH on _PARTITIONTIME and have made the partition filter mandatory.

I assume the partition filter is has automatically added the correct filter and the data was inserted this month (an hour ago).

Why don't I see any results, if the Preview shows results?

Comment: If you remove the where-clause `WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2023-02-20"`, does the query return a result? BR

Comment: Unfortunately, the table is configured to require a partition filter to reduce reads, cost of query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental disconnect between a table Preview in the GCP console and the query.

I'll add more here as I discover more but my testing has shown that the Preview continues to show rows after the table contents are deleted.

Also, deleting the table completely and recreating it and inserting rows seems to force an update of the Preview with latest data, while a `SELECT` query returns nothing, no matter what partition date is used.

It returns nothing even when I disable using cached results in the query settings.

I've logged an issue with Google:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270118631

It could be that BigQuery caching, the wrong partition date and the cached results that the Preview must surely be using, are all conspiring to confuse me.

#### Follow-up

After using BigQuery for a while, I see that it takes about **one hour** for rows inserted via an SDK to show up in queries. New rows do show up in Preview, somehow!

This slowness, combined with caching, causes no data in results for much longer than you'd expect.

The cache is expired when changes to the table are made, but it's not clear whether changes are counted at the moment of ingestion, or the moment of being available to query.

While developing your application, be sure to configure queries not to use caching, or including a non-deterministic function like a timestamp in your SELECT statement also bypasses the cache.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce your issue.

Basically here's what I did.

Created a table with paritiontime on MONTH as you did

```
   CREATE or replace TABLE
      myproject.mydataset.partition_datatest (transaction_id INT64, transaction_date DATE)
    PARTITION BY
      DATE_TRUNC(_PARTITIONTIME, MONTH)
      OPTIONS (
        partition_expiration_days = 3
        );
```

Inserted data into table

```
insert into myproject.mydataset.partition_datatest(transaction_id, transaction_date)  (
  select cast(rand() as int64),  transaction_date from (
select *
 from unnest(generate_date_array('2021-01-01','2023-02-21',INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as transaction_date
  )
);
```

Queried the paritioned table on todays date - NOTE this shows be No data

```
select *, DATE(_PARTITIONTIME), _PARTITIONTIME
from  myproject.mydataset.partition_datatest
where DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2023-02-21"
```

Then I changed the where clause to below given I have partitioned on month, the partition time is set to first day of each month - this returns me the data

```
select *, DATE(_PARTITIONTIME), _PARTITIONTIME
from  myproject.mydataset.partition_datatest.partition_datatest
where DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2023-02-01"
```

Please try with providing the `DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2023-02-01"` instead of `DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2023-02-20"`

Comment: Incredible. Well done and thanks. I assumed a) Google's UI would emit the correct query for my table given that it clearly runs the correct Preview query and b) the query engine would use only the month portion of any given date when the partition filter is by month.